# Promise.all is returning an array of undefined and resolves before being done

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I am having trouble with a function returning an Array of `undefined`.

Here is code:

```js
classMethods.getQueries = function(models, dbId, dateStart, dateEnd) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Fetch database.
    .then(extractQueries, reject)
      .then(sortQueries, reject)
      .then(onlyTen, reject)
      .then(addText, reject)
      .then(function(queries) {
        console.log("getQueries finished", queries); // Array of 10× undefined!
        resolve(queries);
      }, reject);

    // Functions here.
  });
};
```

Everything is fine until the `addText` function:

```js
function addText(queries) {
  return Promise.all(queries.map(function(query) {
    models.queries.findById(query.queryId, {
      raw: true,
      attributes: [ "query" ]
    })
      .then(function(queryFetched) {
        query.text = queryFetched.query;
        console.log(query);
        
        return Promise.resolve(query);
      }, function(error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
  }));
};
```

This is giving me an output like:

```
"getQueries finished" [ undefined ×10 ]

10×
[query database]
{ queryId: "…", text: "…" }
```

I have no idea why the promise is returned while the loop is not finished.

Comment: There's no reason to wrap your promises like that.

Comment: What's the point of the comment?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) accepts an Array of `Promise` objects.
You’re getting an Array of `undefined` because you’re not *returning* any Promise in your [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback:

```js
function addText(queries) {
  return Promise.all(queries.map(function(query) {
    // Add `return` here or the `map` returns an Array of `undefined`.
    return models.queries
      .findById(query.queryId, {
        raw: true,
        attributes: [ "query" ]
      })
      .then(function(queryFetched) {
        query.text = queryFetched.query;
        console.log(query);
        
        return Promise.resolve(query);
      }, function(error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
  }));
};
```

A primitive value such as `undefined` will resolve immediately in `Promise.all`, therefore it resolves before any of the Promises in your callback resolve.

Comment: Ah yes I confused the return of  the map and the then callback. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

So here the solution of my problem:

```
function addText(queries) {
  return Promise.all(queries.map(function(query) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      models.queries.findById(query.queryId, { raw: true, attributes: ['query'] })
      .then(function(queryFetched) {
         query.text = queryFetched.query;
         resolve(query);
      }, reject);

    });
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, my `Promise.all(list)`, results in an array of undefined, I used the same approach of adding a `return` to my function.